# Assign individual service plan to 0365 users

Tags: powershell

I am executing the below script to assign a specific service plan to a bulk user list.

But after execution, the script is assigning all the E3 licenses for that user.

Please let me know where i am going wrong

```
$Creds = Get-Credential

Connect-AzureAD -Credential $Creds

$Users = @()

$Users = Import-Csv "D:\Users.csv"


foreach ($User in $Users)
{
    
 
$EnabledPlans=@()
$LicenseSku = ""

$UserToLicense = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $User.UserName

$EnabledPlans = 'POWERAPPS_O365_P2'

$LicenseSku = Get-AzureADSubscribedSku | Where-Object {$_.SkuPartNumber -eq 'ENTERPRISEPACK'}

$DisabledPlans = $LicenseSku.ServicePlans | ForEach-Object -Process { 
  $_ | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.ServicePlanName -notin $EnabledPlans }
}


$License = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.AssignedLicense
$License.SkuId = $LicenseSku.SkuId

$AssignedLicenses = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.AssignedLicenses
$AssignedLicenses.AddLicenses = $License
$AssignedLicenses.RemoveLicenses = @()
Set-AzureADUserLicense -ObjectId $UserToLicense.ObjectId -AssignedLicenses $AssignedLicenses

}
```

want to enable only this. don't want to change any other settings.

```
$EnabledPlans = 'POWERAPPS_O365_P2'
```

Comment: Can you remove the line `$Users = @()` and then add `"$User test"` to see if your script's loop is fine. It should return `[your_user] test` for each user, if you only have one "test" then your array `$Users` is not good

Comment: @PowerCat: Loop is working fine. just checked .

Comment: Are all the E3 lic assigned to the first user ? My guess is that you are getting all the E3 and then you assign them to the first user that is looped

Comment: As of now there are only one user in that csv file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But after execution, the script is assigning all the E3 licenses for that user.

You appear to follow an example like [this one](https://practical365.com/blog/managing-office-365-licenses-with-azure-ad-v2-powershell-module/#subsku) from Paul Cunningham.

But, you never use your `$DisabledPlans` variable.

I suggest using this core logic.

```
### Admin-modified Variables
# The user receiving the new license. 
$User = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId "User@contoso.com"

# Set the 'usage location' for this user to the United States. 
Set-AzureADUser -ObjectId $User.ObjectId -UsageLocation US

# ServicePlans we want to enable. 
$SkuFeaturesToEnable = @("POWERAPPS_O365_P2")

# Enable the OFFICE 365 E3 license plan. 
# Product Name     String ID         GUID 
# OFFICE 365 E3    ENTERPRISEPACK    6fd2c87f-b296-42f0-b197-1e91e994b900
$StandardLicense = Get-AzureADSubscribedSku | Where-Object {$_.SkuId -eq "6fd2c87f-b296-42f0-b197-1e91e994b900"}

### Initialization 
$License          = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.AssignedLicense
$LicensesToAssign = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.AssignedLicenses

# Dynamically generate a list of disabled ServicePlans. 
# This is required because the ServicePlans in $StandardLicense are enabled by default. 
# This is based on $SkuFeaturesToEnable and should not be modified directly. 
$SkuFeaturesToDisable = $StandardLicense.ServicePlans | ForEach-Object { $_ | Where-Object {$_.ServicePlanName -notin $SkuFeaturesToEnable }}

$License.SkuId = $StandardLicense.SkuId

$License.DisabledPlans = $SkuFeaturesToDisable.ServicePlanId

$LicensesToAssign.AddLicenses = $License

### Main
# Add the $StandardLicense minus $SkuFeaturesToDisable to our user. 
Set-AzureADUserLicense -ObjectId $User.ObjectId -AssignedLicenses $LicensesToAssign
```

Once you demonstrate the core logic is working for one user, you can loop over your list of users like this.

```
Connect-AzureAD 

if ((Read-Host "Type 'yes' to continue") -eq "yes")
{
  # $UserFile contains ObjectId's like "User@contoso.com" with no quotes and one per line. 
  $UserFile = "D:\Users.txt"
  
  $SkuFeaturesToEnable = @("POWERAPPS_O365_P2")
  $StandardLicense = Get-AzureADSubscribedSku | Where-Object {$_.SkuId -eq "6fd2c87f-b296-42f0-b197-1e91e994b900"}
  $License          = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.AssignedLicense
  $LicensesToAssign = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.AssignedLicenses
  $SkuFeaturesToDisable = $StandardLicense.ServicePlans | ForEach-Object { $_ | Where-Object {$_.ServicePlanName -notin $SkuFeaturesToEnable }}
  $License.SkuId = $StandardLicense.SkuId
  $License.DisabledPlans = $SkuFeaturesToDisable.ServicePlanId
  $LicensesToAssign.AddLicenses = $License
  
  Get-Content $UserFile | 
    ForEach-Object {
      $User = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $_ 
      Set-AzureADUser -ObjectId $User.ObjectId -UsageLocation US
      Set-AzureADUserLicense -ObjectId $User.ObjectId -AssignedLicenses $LicensesToAssign
    }
}
else {
  Write-Output "Aborting license change. "
}
```

### References

You might find these references useful.

- [GUIDs for License Plans](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/licensing-service-plan-reference)
- [Note on Licensing Plans vs Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/view-licenses-and-services-with-microsoft-365-powershell)
- [Note on "Usage Location"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/license-users-groups#available-license-plans)
- [What is group-based licensing - Azure Active Directory | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-licensing-whatis-azure-portal)